# insert config in the combobox list item

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-2010

create a new project. 
I insert one ComboBox into the project 
and 1 editbox into the project. 
then I menambhkan string item in combobox
**list of items**

```
server 1 au
server 2 uk
server 3 my
```

after making a string in the combobox then formed a list in combobox.
all I want is to add a config in the string. 
like if i choose **server 1 au** in the editbox combobox displays the server address as **ns.au.server.com**

**ns.au.server.com** server address -> *string* to **server 1 au**

**combobox1**-> select *string* item-> **Server 1 au**

**editbox1** then displays the address **ns.au.server.com**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functionality you ask for is available using TStrings Name-Value pairs.

```
type
  TFormMain = class(TForm)
    ComboBox1: TComboBox;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ComboBox1Change(Sender: TObject);
  private

  public
    FServerConfig : TStrings;
  end;

var
  FormMain: TFormMain;

implementation
{$R *.dfm}

procedure TFormMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var i : integer;
begin
  FServerConfig := TStringList.Create;

  //Add Name = Value pairs
  FServerConfig.Append('Server 1 AU=ns.au.server.com');
  FServerConfig.Append('Server 2 UK=ns.uk.server.com');
  FServerConfig.Append('Server 3 MY=ns.my.server.com');

  for i := 0 to FServerConfig.Count - 1 do
    ComboBox1.Items.Append(FServerConfig. Names[i]);
end;

procedure TFormMain.ComboBox1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Edit1.Text := FServerConfig.Values[ComboBox1.Text];
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to define a class that holds a name and configuration string for your servers like this :-

```
Type
  TServer = Class
  Private
    FName : String;
    FConfig : String;
  Public
    Property Name : String Read FName Write FName;
    Property Config : String Read FConfig Write FConfig;
  End;
```

You can then create instances of your objects and use the `Item's` `AddObject` method to add them to your combo box like this :-

```
Var
  lItem : TServer;
Begin
  lItem := TServer.Create;
  lItem.Name := 'Server 1 AU';
  lItem.Config := 'ns.au.server.com';
  ComboBox1.Items.AddObject(lItem.Name, lItem);
// Add more as required.
End;
```

Then in your Combobox's `OnChange` event you can write :-

```
Var
  lIndex : Integer;
Begin
  lIndex := ComboBox1.ItemIndex;
  If (lIndex <> -1) Then
    Edit1.Text := TServer(ComboBox1.Items.Objects[lIndex]).Config;
End;
```